# Creating a single SELECT using multilevel parent->child array

Tags: php, html, arrays, select

I used the following stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273449/creating-a-multilevel-array-using-parentids-in-php), which was very helpful, in creating a sorted multilevel parent->child array.

The below is a sample multi-level (3 levels) parent->child sorted array based on the sorting method of the above stated thread:

```
Array 
( 
    [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [name] => User Manual 
            [parentId] => 0 
            [children] => Array
                ( 
                    [2] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [name] => Users 
                            [parentId] => 1 
                            [children] => Array 
                                ( 
                                    [4] => Array 
                                        ( 
                                            [name] => Privileges 
                                            [parentId] => 2 
                                        ) 
                                )
                        ) 
                    [3] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [name] => Reference 
                            [parentId] => 1 
                            [children] => Array 
                                ( 
                                    [5] => Array 
                                        ( 
                                            [name] =>  Glossary
                                            [parentId] => 3 
                                        ) 
                                    [6] => Array 
                                        ( 
                                            [name] =>  Index
                                            [parentId] => 3
                                        )
                                ) 
                        ) 
                )
        )
)
```

Now I'd like to take that sorted array and generate a **single** HTML SELECT that displays and represents the parent->child structure like the below example:

```
<option value='1'>User Manual</option>
<option value='2'>User Manual -> Users</option>
<option value='4'>User Manual -> Users -> Privileges</option>
<option value='3'>User Manual -> Reference</option>
<option value='5'>User Manual -> Reference -> Glossary</option>
<option value='6'>User Manual -> Reference -> Index</option>
```

The goal as seen above is to compile a display string that represents the multi-level parent/child path for each item.  The VALUE to each option is the last item in the represented compiled string.  So for the OPTION 'User Manual -> Users -> Privileges' the VALUE is the ID for Privileges, but the display text represents it's parent/child relationship in the array.

The select I create always ends up displaying the list of options like the below:

```
<option value='1'>User Manual</option>
<option value='2'>User Manual -> Users</option>
<option value='4'>Users -> Privileges</option>
<option value='3'>User Manual -> Reference</option>
<option value='5'>Reference -> Glossary</option>
<option value='6'>Reference -> Index</option>
```

You can see that it only is able to keep track of one level of the parent/child relationship.

My function that processes the array to create the selects options list is as follows:

```
function buildOptions($arr, $target, $parent = NULL) {
  $html = "";
  foreach ( $arr as $key => $v ) 
  {
    if (array_key_exists('children', $v))
    {
      if ( $key == $target )
        $html .= "<option value='$key' selected>$parent {$v['name']}</option>\n";
      else
        $html .= "<option value='$key'>$parent {$v['name']}</option>\n";

      $html .= buildOptions($v['children'],$target,$v['name']." > ");
    }
    else if ( $key == $target )
      $html .= "<option value='$key' selected>$parent {$v['name']}</option>\n";
    else
      $html .= "<option value='$key'>$parent {$v['name']}</option>\n";

  }

  return $html;
}
```

I'm having trouble in keeping track of the previous X parent.name when there is more than one level.  Any help here would be welcomed.  Thank you!

Comment: What does your array look like? Smells like recursion may be involved.

Comment: Your right, I use recursion to get the 2 levels displayed so the problem I have is retaining the tree structure history past two levels.  The problem is the recursion works through a pre-sorted array.  It deals with each child and it's children as it progresses, naturally.  So when it steps back to a prior child I'm having a hard time conceptualizing stepping back the string.  Hopefully that makes sense.  I'll update my post with an array example.

Comment: @Brad: There is no recursive call in your snippet. What's `toUL`? What's `$target`? Would you consider using visual cues (indentation) instead of repeating the complete path for expressing hierarchy?

Comment: @nikc: Sorry about that.  I edited the post to fix that toUL.  I renamed the function to buildOptions for this post and  forgot to update the recursive callback.  I would be interested in visual cues and would assume that the visual cues(indentation) would be based on the depth of the tree.  I considered this but my mind hasn't been able to wrap itself around the idea as it seems very similar to what I'm originally trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Brad: It is pretty much exactly the same, but with less bytes to transfer and less stuff to read for the end user ;-) [and you only need to pass an `int` down the recursion stack, replace `$parent = null` with `$level = 0` and call `buildOptions(<...>, $level + 1)` and then use `$level` as a margin/padding multiplier.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your recursive invocation this way, and you should get the full hierarchy on each node:

```
function buildOptions($arr, $target, $parent = NULL) {
  $html = "";
  foreach ( $arr as $key => $v )
  {
    if ( $key == $target )
      $html .= "<option value='$key' selected>$parent {$v['name']}</option>\n";
    else
      $html .= "<option value='$key'>$parent {$v['name']}</option>\n";

    if (array_key_exists('children', $v)) 
      $html .= buildOptions($v['children'],$target,$parent . $v['name']." > ");
  }

  return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I can't believe I was that close.  Man..and I could swear I tried that.  Too many hours staring at the same problem I think.

Comment: I can't post my own answers yet as a follow up, but I slightly modified your response to check if (!$parent) then only print $v['name']." -> ", else print $parent.$v['name']." -> ".

Comment: Just a note: If i stare too many hours at a problem I just stand up and go away...maybe to sniff some fresh air outside. 1-2 hour later I usually solve the problem within 10 minutes. This worked for me. :)

Comment: @edem: Indeed!  

guido: Your updated version worked flawless.  Thanks again.