# Remove key from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Hi I am going to make tree array for multilevel category menu and I have found the solution from below link:

[`stackoverflow answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273449/creating-a-multilevel-array-using-parentids-in-php)

But my problem is that i am getting output of my array as **FORMAT-1** and in the above given link the source array required as **FORMAT-2**

So can you please give me a hand for how to convert my array from **FORMAT-1** to **FORMAT-2**

**FORMAT-1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 11
            [category_name] => Accessories
            [parent_category_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 12
            [category_name] => Keyrings
            [parent_category_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 13
            [category_name] => Photo Frames/Photo Albums
            [parent_category_id] => 1
        )

)
```

**FORMAT-2** (I want output as below)

```
Array(
        Array(
                'category_id' => 11
                'category_name' => 'Accessories'
                'parent_category_id' => 1
            ),

        Array(
                'category_id' => 12
                'category_name' => 'Keyrings'
                'parent_category_id' => 1
            ),

        Array(
                'category_id' => 13
                'category_name' => 'Photo Frames/Photo Albums'
                'parent_category_id' => 1
            )

    );
```

Thanks in advance for your help and much appreciated

Comment: What is wrong with array 1?

Comment: These are slightly different representations of a same array. Nothing is wrong here.

Comment: Can you explain more? What is really your problem because those two FORMATS are the same.

Comment: Please check the stackoverflow answer link in that solution function "buildTree" required array parameter as in format-2. is there any alternative for that?

Answer (score 1):

### Both arrays are more are like same..

Format-1 looks `print_r($yourarray);` version

Format-2 looks like `var_export($yourarray);` version.

You need to have a look at the debugger functions.. `print_r()`, `var_dump()` and `var_export()`.

Comment: i did it but you can check the stackoverflow answer link then you can find that the function "buildTree" required array parameter as in format-2. is there any alternative for that?

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is debugging you may use `<pre>var_dump()</pre>`.