# Cakephp working whit Cell

Tags: cakephp, cell

Hi I have a trouble whit Cell in my application I follow the tutorial but did not work for me
here is my code https://github.com/boguda/okpionir.git
I bake cell for News and add display function
I want to use this cell on my static page src/Template/Pages/pocetna.ctp
but it doesn't work

Comment: Please put your code in the question, also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change

```
<?php  $cell = $this->cell('News'); ?>
<?= $cell ?>
```

to

```
<?= $this->cell('News::display'); ?>
```

Call Cell has to refer to specific method name

---

EDIT: 
Also you have an error in your **src/View/Cell/NewsCell**

```
public function display()
    {
        $this->loadModel('News');
   ----> $top_news= $this->News->find()
        ->select('title')
        ->order(['created'=>'DESC'])
        ->limit(3)
        ->toArray();
        $this->set('top_news' => $news); <----- 
    }
```

should be:

```
$this->set('top_news', $top_news);
```

or

```
$this->set(compact('top_news'));
```

And your view **Template/Cell/News/display.ctp** might look like this

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <?php foreach ($top_news as $news): ?>
        <li><?= h($news['title']); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I use this to show data from model to my home page. Can I use this to create my dynamic manu in element. Thanks for this

Comment: @boguda sure! check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438247/cakephp3-using-recursive-function-in-view-cells/37567681#37567681)